# paste(1) in SQL

Tags: sql, record

How in SQL could you "zip" together records in separate tables (à la the UNIX `paste(1)` utility)?

For example, assuming two tables, `A` and `B`, like so:

```
   A          B
========    ====
Harkness    unu
Costello    du
Sato        tri
Harper
Jones
```

How could you produce a single result set

```
   NAME  | NUM
===============
Harkness | unu
Costello | du
Sato     | tri
Harper   | NULL
Jones    | NULL
```

?

Comment: Are there any other fields on the tables, maybe a key that relates records in A to B?

Comment: @Tom, no, the tables are not materially related (no keys to get a one-to-one mapping).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `SQL Server 2005`, `Oracle 9i` and `PostgreSQL 8.4` and higher:

```
SELECT  name, num
FROM    (
        SELECT  name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS rn
        FROM    a
        ) qa
LEFT JOIN
        (
        SELECT  num, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS rn
        FROM    b
        ) qb
ON      qb.rn = qa.rn
ORDER BY
        qa.rn
```

Note that `ROW_NUMBER()` requires that the records are explicitly sorted.

If you don't have a column similar to `id`, you cannot sort the records in order other than alphabetical, since relational databases have no concept of implicit record order.

Answer (score 1):

Without some identifying information to associate rows in one to another you shouldn't. Order or records in SQL should not matter, now if you altered your table to be like.

```
 ID | NAME
===============
1 | Harkness
2 | Costello
3 | Sato 
4 | Harper
5 | Jones

ID | Num
=========
 1| uno
2 | du
3 | tri
```

Then a simple

```
SELECT * FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.ID=B.ID;
```

Comment: +1 for stating that "[I] shouldn't" be doing this.  (It's true, I shouldn't.)