# How to write an SQL query to combine two already-ordered tables horizontally with different columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables which I would like to place side-by-side exactly as they are. For example,

```
tableOne                              tableTwo
columnOne | columnTwo | columnThree   columnI | columnII | columnIII
```

The data in the two tables do not need to be related whatsoever -- the tables have the same row count -- and the data is already sorted in the two tables. Basically, I would like to do a `full outer join` on the two tables without an `on` operator.

How can I do this in a SQL query?

Comment: A query needs an order by expression to guarantee the order of the rows. By which column(s) is the data ordered?

Comment: What do you mean the table is already ordered? Do you have a column that tells you that in each table?

Comment: So you know, you should **NEVER** consider rows in a table to be 'sorted' (and never as an index directly).  The only way for you to garuantee 'order' is to **specify** it with an `ORDER BY` clause _at the time of the request_.  SQL was specifically designed so that, unless that clause was used, the order of the rows was unimportant.  Anything else is asking for trouble.

Comment: Material duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/2676138/132382

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you *do* want an ON operator - you just seem to want it to work automatically, which won't happen.

If you're saying Row 1 of tableOne maps to Row 1 of tableTwo, then you need to add a row column to each table and then join on it.

If you don't specify a join condition, you'll do a `cross join` that joins every row from tableOne to every row in tableTwo, which obviously isn't what you're looking for.

So do something like this:

```
select * from 
  (select *, row_number() over (order by 1) as RN from tableOne) a
  inner join (select *, row_number() over (order by 1) as RN from tableTwo) b
     on a.RN = b.RN
```

Comment: +1 - Agreed, this is where I'm thinking the OP want to go with this.